# What do the columns in Perl's Devel::Cover output mean?

Tags: perl, code-coverage, devel-cover

In the ["Perl build, unit testing, code coverage: A complete working example by Kurt W. Leucht"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533553/perl-build-unit-testing-code-coverage-a-complete-working-example/) we see that we run `build testcover` and bet the coverage report. We see the result in the figure "File Cover". Can anyone tell what does the number shown under stmt, bran, sub and time indicate?

Comment: In what? Is that a book? Amazon doesn't appear to have heard of the author.

Comment: in the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533553/perl-build-unit-testing-code-coverage-a-complete-working-example/533577#533577

Comment: You should post this question as a comment on the original SO post, not here.

Answer (score 8):

See [Paul Johnson's presentations](http://www.pjcj.net/presentations/) on [`Devel::Cover`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::Cover), for instance [this one](http://www.pjcj.net/presentations/yapc-eu-2003-dc/slide001.html).

Comment: Or even just read the [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover) docs.

Comment: But neither of those mention the "time" column