# Test Coverage in Jenkins for a Perl application

Tags: perl, unit-testing, jenkins, code-coverage, clover

I just implemented an excellent example of test coverage in Perl described at [Perl, Code Coverage Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533553/perl-build-unit-testing-code-coverage-a-complete-working-example)

But that required Module::Build , Now what if i have existing Perl Application which does NOT have the Module::Build instrumentation, is there a way to get test coverage for unit or functional tests ?

I looked at :

```
Clean up from previous test run (optional)
  cover -delete

  #Test run with coverage instrumentation
  PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover prove -r t

  #Collect covered and caller information
  #  Run this _before_ running "cover"
  #  Don't run with Devel::Cover enabled
  covered runs
    - or e.g. -
  covered runs --rex_skip_test_file='/your-prove-file.pl$/' \
          --rex_skip_source_file='{app_cpan_deps/}'

  #Post process to generate covered database
  cover -report Html_basic


  %perl -d:Coverage -Iblib/lib test.pl
```

But this seems to indicate Code Coverage while running the application.

I want to be able to get a Clover or Cobertura Compatible output, so i can integrate it with email-ext in Jenkins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Task::Jenkins](https://metacpan.org/module/Task::Jenkins) may be of some help.  It has instructions about how to publish the Devel::Cover HTML reports through Jenkins, as well as info about adapting other Perl tools to Jenkins.

Jira has some instructions about [integrating Devel::Cover into Jenkins](https://logiclab.jira.com/wiki/display/OPEN/Devel-Cover).

To get code coverage for any Perl process (test, application, server, whatever) you set the `PERL5OPT` environment variable to `-MDevel::Cover` which is like putting `use Devel::Cover` in the program.  If your command to execute tests is `perl something_test` then you'd run `PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover perl something_test`.

If you're using `prove`, use `HARNESS_PERL_SWITCHES=-MDevel::Cover prove <normal prove arguments>`.  This tells `prove` to load `Devel::Cover` when running the tests, but avoids gathering coverage for prove itself.

Comment: does that mean PERL5OPT=-MDevel::Cover prove --timer --formatter=TAP::Formatter::JUnit -v -r . > perlapp_smoke.xml 2>perlapp_smoke.err
would NOT work ? Since it does not have perl something_test format, but rather has prove.

Comment: Thanks, How to get the HTML report while running with prove?

Comment: Figured out. `cover -test` generated the HTMLs. Thanks!