# How do I change the default Module::Build / Test::More directory from "lib" to something else?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, devel-cover, module-build, test-more

Using the directory and file architecture in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533553/perl-build-unit-testing-code-coverage-a-complete-working-example) on Perl Unit testing and Code Coverage (which btw was VERY helpful), I copied the files I'll be running unit tests and code coverage on into a new "lib" directory and it works like a charm!

However, I need the module to look in an existing "scripts" directory..

I have combed through the Module::Build documentation on [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~leont/Module-Build-0.4205/lib/Module/Build/Cookbook.pm#Adding_new_file_types_to_the_build_process), but I still get a *Can't find file lib/processBuildSubs.pm* error

Here's what I have thus far...

```
use strict;
use Module::Build;


my $newBuild = Module::Build->new(

    module_name         => 'processBuildSubs',
    license             => 'perl',
    dist_abstract       => 'processBuildSubs Unit Test',
    dist_author         => 'me@myemail.com',
    build_requires      => {
           'Test::More' => '0.10',
    },

);

$newBuild->create_build_script();
```

UPDATE!

Also just tried this..

```
my $newBuild = Module::Build->new(

    module_name     => 'scripts::processBuildSubs',
    pm_files        => {'processBuildSubs.pm' => 'lib/processBuildSubs.pm'},
    license         => 'perl',
    dist_abstract       => 'processBuildSubs Unit Test',
    dist_author         => 'me@myemail.com',
    build_requires  => {
        'Test::More' => '0.10',
    },

);
```

Some progress I guess, it seems to be looking in *lib/scripts/..*, still not quite what I need though..

UPDATE!

Sort of a hack job, but for now it does the trick for me..

```
#!/bin/bash

mv scripts lib
perl ./Build.pl
perl ./Build testcover
mv lib scripts
firefox cover_db/coverage.html
```

I run this script to change the directory name, run the tests/coverage and change the directory name back... Anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently tell Module::Build to use another directory other than "lib" (I looked at the source code for Module::Build and `lib` seems to be pretty hard coded.)

You could create a symlink:

```
ln -s scripts lib
```

And this would allow Module::Build to find it.